# How to define multiple character parenthesis in SMIE

Tags: emacs, indentation, parentheses, auto-indent, smie

I copied the the code in the GNU manual about SMIE. The indent of `begin` and `end` works fine.

```
(defvar sample-smie-grammar
  (smie-prec2->grammar
   (smie-bnf->prec2
    '((id)
      (inst ("begin" insts "end")
            ("if" exp "then" inst "else" inst)
            (id ":=" exp)
            (exp))
      (insts (insts ";" insts) (inst))
      (exp (exp "+" exp)
           (exp "*" exp)
           ("(" exps ")"))
      (exps (exps "," exps) (exp)))
    '((assoc ";"))
    '((assoc ","))
    '((assoc "+") (assoc "*")))))
```

But when I try to add `class`/`endclass`, `module`/`endmodule` as below, the new added pairs do not indent at all. When I enable `show-paren-mode`. They are not highlighted as `begin` and `end` does.

```
(defvar sample-smie-grammar
  (smie-prec2->grammar
   (smie-bnf->prec2
    '((id)
      (inst ("begin" insts "end")
            ("module" insts "endmodule")
            ("class" insts "endclass")
            ("if" exp "then" inst "else" inst)
            (id ":=" exp)
            (exp))
      (insts (insts ";" insts) (inst))
      (exp (exp "+" exp)
           (exp "*" exp)
           ("(" exps ")"))
      (exps (exps "," exps) (exp)))
    '((assoc ";"))
    '((assoc ","))
    '((assoc "+") (assoc "*")))))
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless description of the behavior.

Comment: Sorry about my bad English. Add some words try to make it clear.

Comment: The problem is probably in the methodology.  So please tell us *exactly* in excruciating detail how you try it: which keys you hit, and in which order.